# I need to write a variable's value(which will hold the value present in table td) to the textbox dynamically using edit button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code/function in jquery to create a table row dynamically,which will contain the button edit in td of the table tr and it is to be used to intitate a function onclick which will pass its row's values to the form fields which i have created.

```
 function addRow() {
        debugger;
        var table = $('#basicTable');
        var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(table);
        $('<td></td>').text($('#txt1').val()).appendTo(row);
        $('<td></td>').text($('#txt2').val()).appendTo(row);
        $('<td></td>').text($('#txt3').val()).appendTo(row);
        $('<td><input type="button" id="btnedit" value="Edit" /></td>').appendTo(row);
        $('<td><input type="button" id="btndel" value="Delete" class="rem" /></td>').appendTo(row);
        $("#form").trigger('reset');

        return table;
    }
```

while below is the jquery code which gets called when the click event is initiated for the edit button:

```
  $("#btnedit").click(function () {
                debugger;
                var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
                var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
                var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
                var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
               $("#txt1").val(tdName).html();

               $("#txt2").val(tdEmail);
               $("#txt3").val(tdPhone);


            });
```

But when i run the code using debugger and check for the value contained in the varaible tdName it shows like this: `[<td>Kamal Singh</td>]` and in the textbox it shows like [object,object],also i need one of the textbox to be focused so as to update the details.

Comment: why are you sending a jquery object as a value to a input field?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for it...

Comment: actually i'm holding the user's data entered in form through the object in table created dynamically on submit event,so basically i need to let the user update/edit his details by passing/sending those previous values entered by the user into the input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly binding object to text box. You have to bind HTML.
Please find the below link, it will be helpful to you.
https://jsfiddle.net/9ah90pzu/

```
 [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/9ah90pzu/
```

Comment: that almost did my work but additionally i need one of the textbox to get focus.

Comment: Do you want to focus onload then. Use this  $('#txt1').focus();